# Illegal reference to net data in my inout datatype

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am writing code in Verilog for creating a memory block capable to read and write data.

```
module memory( wr_n , rst_n ,data ,clk ,add , en);    

input wire wr_n;    
input wire rst_n;    
input wire clk;    
input wire en;    

parameter size = 255;    
parameter n = 7;    

inout wire [n:0] data;    
input wire [n:0] add;    

reg [n:0] mem [size:0];    
integer i;    

always @( posedge clk , negedge rst_n)    
begin    
    if(!rst_n)    
    begin        
        for( i=0; i<=size; i=i+1 )    
        begin    
            mem[i] <= 8'hff;    
        end    
    end    

    else    
    begin    
        if(en)    
        begin       
            if(!wr_n)                   //read
                data <= mem[add];    
            else                        //write
                mem[add] <= data;       
        end    
    
        else    
             data = 8'h z;    
    end      
end
endmodule
```

Here when I use a continuous assignment before `data`, I get an error like:

> "LHS in procedural assignment may not be a net:data"

even if I have declared it as wire.
In my test bench I have declared `data` as `reg` type because when I declare it as net, it shows again the

> "Illegal reference to net error".

I am not able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way of using an inout port, it should be isolated from the logic to avoid conflicts while reading and writing, remember whenever you use inout ports make sure the points mentioned in the [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/23095/17800) are satisfied.

One such solution is declare a temporary variable for reading and writing and
by using continuous assignment statement assign values to bidirectional port.

Following snippet will give you some more clearance of how the error can be avoided

```
reg [n:0] temp; // declare a variable and try to read and write with this variable

if(!wr_n)                   //read
  temp   <= mem[add];    
else                        //write
  mem[add] <= temp;       

  assign data = (wr_n==0)? temp : {n{1'bz}};
```

Remove the `else` part having   `data = 8'h z;`  there cannot be two else for single if statement as per LRM.

Comment: I tried it. But still I am getting "data may not be a net " in the assign statement you suggested above. and yeah how am I supposed to pass the data value which I want to write in memory using temp because that value I am entering from my test bench.

Comment: can you check the [link-edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Vy9) were I tried

Comment: I can compile it now!.. Thanks..but i am still getting an error in my test bench when I try to assign any value to data bus for write operation under the initial statement ..The error is again "Illegal reference to net DATA" . and yeah I have declared it as net .

Comment: If at all It is just a method as to how the usage should be to avoid errors you mentioned in the ques, it is not necessary that all the function will work correctly based on this method, from your code I see lot of flaws, If possible why can't you share the tb in the link edaplayground I provided, I have already a sample tb at [link](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Vy9)

Answer (score 1):

The inout port 'data' is of type `wire`. So, it cannot be used on the left hand side of the `<=` expression in a procedural block (always block and initial block).

So we should use continuous assignment statements like

```
assign data = (wr_n == 0)? mem[add]:n{1'bz};
```

The same holds true when we are driving any values on the inout port form the test bench. The signal connecting to the inout port from the test bench must be of type wire. And hence it should also be written using continuous assignment statements.

```
assign testbench_inout_signal = (wr_n == 0)? value_to_be_written :n{1'bz};
```